# Will termites come in with mulch

Tags: termite

I am hearing that termites come through mulch, is that true? What do you guys use as an alternative? I see some people use Pine straw mulch, will that help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was concerned about this too. Not so much termites being in the mulch, but attracting them towards my house by surrounding it with delicious decaying wood that is often wet from watering.

I used rubber mulch that is made from recycled tires, which won't attract insects and looks reasonably close to regular mulch. Plus Recycling!

The main downside is that it gets SUPER hot in the summer. Enough to burn your hand while working in the garden bed in Texas summers.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for any wood destroying pest to make it through the debarker, and then the hammer hog that smashes the bark into “hog fuel” or “mulch”.

I work in a mill and have used many truck loads with no problems probably because the pests are normally deeper in the wood than the bark layer but it is possible.

Comment: Regardless of whether the pest is in the mulch - they can find and attack the mulch afterwards. Depends on your local area's pests.